# symfony doctrine uuid on maria not working

Tags: symfony, mariadb, doctrine, uuid

in my symfony 6.4 project I have defined the id in my user class as

```
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "uuid", unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "CUSTOM")]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: UuidGenerator::class)]
    private ?Uuid $id;
    ...
}
```

There is another entity to store user logins where the reference to the user is defined as

```
class UserLogin
{
  ...    
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'userLogins')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $user = null;
  ...
}
```

I installed MariaDB 11.3.2 and my DATABASE_URL in .env is

```
DATABASE_URL="mysqli://...?serverVersion=mariadb-11.3.2&charset=utf8".
```

In the migrations created by "symfony console make:migration" I manually edited the type of user.id and userlogin.user_id to the type uuid which is available since maria 10.7.

Then I inserted the first user "manually" which means by handmade sql statement.

And now we come to the point. On a users login I do

```
$ul = new UserLogin();
$ul->setTs(new DateTime())
   ->setUser($token->getUser())
   ->setIp($request->getClientIp());
$this->em->persist($ul);
$this->em->flush();
```

This causes an error. The system tells me, that the foreign key on userlogin.user_id is invalid. This is caused by a value that is simply bullshit. Instead of giving a uuid, it writes a packed binary(16) thing.

After a little debug, I found out, that in the class Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Types\AbstractUidType within the method convertToDatabaseValue there is a line

```
$toString = $this->hasNativeGuidType($platform) ? 'toRfc4122' : 'toBinary';
```

that always results in 'toBinary'.

I already tried updating all libs via composer, but it seems as if symfony and doctrine don't know about native uuid types in maria (and mysql), even though 10.7 was first released in 2021.

Does anybody out there know how to solve that (without editing vendor files which is always a bad idea)?

Comment: Can you show us the SQL?

Comment: If its Doctrine could it be not implemented yet - https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/5804?

Comment: Try mapping the uuid types to string, in the Doctrine configuration

Comment: Thanks for watching and answering, but I gave up. DBAL is unable to handle that stuff, even 4.01 (the current one) does not support it. Even if I manage to override the problems (by extending the classes in vendor) it fails on creating a migration because of unkown database type. I go back to "standard" uuid-handling of symfony.